# Parsing non-standard date element using xmlschema

Tags: python, xsd

I have an xsd schema file, which include the following definition:

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
<xs:element name="CreateDate" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="8"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
...
```

And an xml file which includes the following element:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...
<!-- format is: YYYY/dd/mm -->
<CreateDate>2020/10/22</CreateDate>
...
```

I'm using [xmlschema](https://github.com/sissaschool/xmlschema) to parse the xml file like so:

```python
schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema(schema_file)
element = schema.to_dict(xml_file, datetime_types=True)
```

Obviously, *CreateDate* is parsed to a string instead of a `Date` object. Questions:

1. Is it possible to change the xsd definition, so that `xmlschema` automatically parses *CreateDate* to `Date` using format *"YYYY/mm/dd"*?
2. If not, I guess I need intercept the parsing using [`value_hook`](https://xmlschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#control-the-decoding-of-elements) or [`element_hook`](https://xmlschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#control-the-decoding-of-elements) arguments to `to_dict()`, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Even if you analyse the definition of CreateDate all you'll ever know is its length boundaries. Far more important is the format. Both YYYY/MM/DD and YYYY-MM-DD would be valid as far as that definition is concerned but they're clearly not the same thing. So, in Python you'd have to do some kind of analysis of the actual string to [try to] figure out what (if any) separators are in play. Also, within the definition of CreateDate you could have DDMMYYYY or MMDDYYYY. That might be a challenge!

Comment: @DarkKnight you are right, but in this case I can safely assume it is YYYY/mm/dd

Comment: If you can assume that it's YYYY/mm/dd then I fail to see the point of your question. Be sure to familiarise yourself with the strptime() function from the *datetime* module

Comment: I want xmlschema to parse it automatically, not manually traverse the resulting dict for any element called 'CreateDate'. Namely, it would be great if I could annotate the xsd type with the desired format, and let the parsing library do the rest.

Comment: It makes no sense for any XML parser to parse the `CreateDate` element as a date because it's base type is `xs:string`. If the base type was `xs:date` or `xs:datetime` then yeah.

Comment: @mamift I disagree. It makes perfect sense to be able to configure / tweak / override parsers to do what you need. In my case, the xml files are legacy, and I cannot change their content.

Comment: Schemas ARE the way to customize the behaviour of the XML parser, but they do so according to a standard. In this case it's https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/

Your schema is already telling the parser to parse this `CreateDate` element as a string, but if you want it as a date, then you need to write your own logic for that to occur, post schema validation + parsing. If you could customise the behaviour of the parser to ignore what's in the XSD, then yeah you could get it to do whatever you want, but then it's not longer standards compliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only find the hook option on `iter_decode`, here is an example that just assumes a single element schema and instance:

```
from pprint import pprint

import xmlschema

from elementpath import datatypes

from datetime import datetime

schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema('schema1.xsd')

def my_element_hook(elementData, xsdElement, xsdType):
    thisDate = datetime.strptime(elementData.text, '%Y/%m/%d')
    return xmlschema.ElementData(tag=elementData.tag,text=datatypes.Date10(thisDate.year, thisDate.month, thisDate.day),attributes=None,content=None)


for value in schema.iter_decode('sample1.xml',datetime_types=True,element_hook=my_element_hook):
    pprint(value)
```

For a sample sample1.xml like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- format is: YYYY/mm/dd -->
<CreateDate>2020/10/22</CreateDate>
```

and a schema

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="CreateDate">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="8"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

I get e.g. `Date10(2020, 10, 22)`.

For a more complex schema I guess the element hook needs to return `elementData` unchanged for the elements you don't want to manipulate and then for e.g. `elementData.tag = 'CreateDate'` use the presented code e.g.

```
def my_element_hook(elementData, xsdElement, xsdType):
    if elementData.tag == 'CreateDate':
        thisDate = datetime.strptime(elementData.text, '%Y/%m/%d')
        return xmlschema.ElementData(tag=elementData.tag,text=datatypes.Date10(thisDate.year, thisDate.month, thisDate.day),attributes=None,content=None)
    else:
        return elementData
```